# Why is the shader smooth going crazy?

Tags: shaders

As the title suggests, after running the mirror modifier to the object, I found myself with a completely wrong shader, I checked the scale, normals, junctions and everything is correct

[image: Shading impazzito]

Comment: If you've enabled the Shade Smooth, that's what's going to happen, but if you really need Shade Smooth, you can enable the Auto-Smooth option

Comment: Auto-Smooth option is abilited

Comment: could you please share your object? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/